# Join tables on most recent date and value

Tags: powershell

## WSHOSHO data

```
PS C:\Users\dharm\Dropbox\Documents> $wshosho_data | ft *

DATE       WSHOSHO
----       -------
2023-02-08 8024104.0
2023-02-15 7990467.0
2023-02-22 7986887.0
2023-03-01 7948534.0
2023-03-08 7948335.0
2023-03-15 7940014.0
2023-03-22 7936558.0
2023-03-29 7926131.0
2023-04-05 7877114.0
2023-04-12 7877741.0
```

## RRP data

```
PS C:\Users\dharm\Dropbox\Documents> $rrp_data | ft *

operationDate totalAmtAccepted
------------- ----------------
2023-04-14    2253786000000
2023-04-13    2321699000000   
2023-04-12    2303862000000
2023-04-11    2297208000000
2023-04-10    2239655000000
2023-04-06    2173663000000
2023-04-05    2243011000000
2023-04-04    2219375000000
2023-04-03    2221010000000
2023-03-31    2375171000000
```

## Combined

I'd like to combine these into a single table such that for each common date, the most recent data value is used.

I.e. for the above, it should look like this:

```
PS C:\Users\dharm\Dropbox\Documents> $table | ft *

date       wshosho   rrp
----       -------   ---
2023-02-08 8024104.0
2023-02-15 7990467.0
2023-02-22 7986887.0
2023-03-01 7948534.0
2023-03-08 7948335.0
2023-03-15 7940014.0
2023-03-22 7936558.0
2023-03-29 7926131.0
2023-03-31 7926131.0 2375171000000
2023-04-03 7926131.0 2221010000000
2023-04-04 7926131.0 2219375000000
2023-04-05 7877114.0 2243011000000
2023-04-06 7877114.0 2173663000000
2023-04-10 7877114.0 2239655000000
2023-04-11 7877114.0 2297208000000
2023-04-12 7877741.0 2303862000000
2023-04-13 7877741.0 2321699000000
2023-04-14 7877741.0 2253786000000
```

There you can see, for `2023-04-14`, a `WSHOSHO` value isn't present, so the the most recent value  (from `2023-04-12` is used).

Similarly, for `2023-04-11`, a `WSHOSHO` value isn't present, so the value from `2023-04-05` is used.

And so forth.

## Manual approach

Here's a manual approach to joining them.

```
$wshosho_sorted = $wshosho_data | Sort-Object DATE
$rrp_sorted     = $rrp_data     | Sort-Object operationDate

$wshosho_dates = $wshosho_sorted | ForEach-Object DATE
$rrp_dates     = $rrp_sorted     | ForEach-Object operationDate

$dates = $rrp_dates + $wshosho_dates | Sort-Object | Select-Object -Unique

$table = foreach ($date in $dates)
{
    $rrp_record     = $rrp_sorted.Where(     { $_.operationDate -le $date }, 'Last' )[0]
    $wshosho_record = $wshosho_sorted.Where( { $_.DATE          -le $date }, 'Last' )[0]

    $rrp_item     = $rrp_record.totalAmtAccepted
    $wshosho_item = $wshosho_record.WSHOSHO

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        date    = $date
        wshosho = $wshosho_item
        rrp     = $rrp_item
    }
}

$table | ft *
```

## Function approach

Here's a generalized function approach which works with any number of columns.

```
function combine-columns-alt ($specs)
{
    foreach ($spec in $specs)
    {
        $spec.sorted = $spec.data | Sort-Object $spec.date_prop

        $spec.dates = $spec.sorted | ForEach-Object $spec.date_prop
    }

    $dates = $specs | ForEach-Object dates | Sort-Object | Select-Object -Unique

    foreach ($date in $dates)
    {
        $obj = [PSCustomObject]@{ date = $date }
       
        foreach ($spec in $specs)
        {
            $result = $spec.sorted.Where( { $_.($spec.date_prop) -le $date }, 'Last' )

            $val = if ($result.Count -eq 0) { $null } else { $result[0].($spec.prop) }

            $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $spec.prop -Value $val
        }

        $obj
    }
}
```

It can be called as follows:

```
$specs = @(
    [ordered] @{ data = $wshosho_data; date_prop = 'DATE';          prop = 'WSHOSHO' }
    [ordered] @{ data = $rrp_data;     date_prop = 'operationDate'; prop = 'totalAmtAccepted' }
)

$tbl = combine-columns-alt $specs
```

## Question

The above approach appears to work.

My question is, is there a better or more idiomatic approach for PowerShell?

I'm wondering if there's a more direct or efficient way to implement this.

Just want to make sure I'm not missing some more elegant approach before going forward with the above `combine-columns-alt` function.

## Sample data

Here's some sample data for 3 columns if you'd like to run the above code.

```
$wshosho_data = @"
"DATE","WSHOSHO"
"2023-02-08","8024104.0"
"2023-02-15","7990467.0"
"2023-02-22","7986887.0"
"2023-03-01","7948534.0"
"2023-03-08","7948335.0"
"2023-03-15","7940014.0"
"2023-03-22","7936558.0"
"2023-03-29","7926131.0"
"2023-04-05","7877114.0"
"2023-04-12","7877741.0"
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$rrp_data = @"
"operationDate","totalAmtAccepted"
"2023-04-14","2253786000000"
"2023-04-13","2321699000000"
"2023-04-12","2303862000000"
"2023-04-11","2297208000000"
"2023-04-10","2239655000000"
"2023-04-06","2173663000000"
"2023-04-05","2243011000000"
"2023-04-04","2219375000000"
"2023-04-03","2221010000000"
"2023-03-31","2375171000000"
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$tga_data = @"
"record_date","open_today_bal"
"2023-03-31","177692"
"2023-04-03","173105"
"2023-04-04","140347"
"2023-04-05","140688"
"2023-04-06","112965"
"2023-04-07","110822"
"2023-04-10","125004"
"2023-04-11","107469"
"2023-04-12","86554"
"2023-04-13","99488"
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

You can combine all three columns as follows:

```
$specs = @(
    [ordered] @{ data = $wshosho_data; date_prop = 'DATE';          prop = 'WSHOSHO' }
    [ordered] @{ data = $rrp_data;     date_prop = 'operationDate'; prop = 'totalAmtAccepted' }
    [ordered] @{ data = $tga_data;     date_prop = 'record_date';   prop = 'open_today_bal' }
)

$tbl = combine-columns-alt $specs
```

You should get:

```
PS C:\Users\dharm\Dropbox\Documents> $tbl | ft *

date       WSHOSHO   totalAmtAccepted open_today_bal
----       -------   ---------------- --------------
2023-02-08 8024104.0
2023-02-15 7990467.0
2023-02-22 7986887.0
2023-03-01 7948534.0
2023-03-08 7948335.0
2023-03-15 7940014.0
2023-03-22 7936558.0
2023-03-29 7926131.0
2023-03-31 7926131.0 2375171000000    177692        
2023-04-03 7926131.0 2221010000000    173105
2023-04-04 7926131.0 2219375000000    140347
2023-04-05 7877114.0 2243011000000    140688
2023-04-06 7877114.0 2173663000000    112965
2023-04-07 7877114.0 2173663000000    110822
2023-04-10 7877114.0 2239655000000    125004
2023-04-11 7877114.0 2297208000000    107469
2023-04-12 7877741.0 2303862000000    86554
2023-04-13 7877741.0 2321699000000    99488
2023-04-14 7877741.0 2253786000000    99488
```

## SQL Approach

This technique is similar to joins in SQL.

As an aside, here's how this same data is handled in SQL:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/325791/join-and-use-most-recent-data-if-null

## Real world data

The above small CSV datasets were meant for use in demonstrating the technique.

Here's some code which retrieves:

```
- WSHOSHO via St Louis Fed  API
- RRP     via New York Fed  API
- TGA     via U.S. Treasury API
```

and joins the resulting columns.

```
$wshosho_result = Invoke-RestMethod 'https://fred.stlouisfed.org/graph/fredgraph.csv?id=WSHOSHO' | ConvertFrom-Csv
$rrp_result     = Invoke-RestMethod ('https://markets.newyorkfed.org/api/rp/reverserepo/propositions/search.json?startDate={0}' -f '2022-04-08')
$tga_result     = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri ('https://api.fiscaldata.treasury.gov/services/api/fiscal_service/v1/accounting/dts/dts_table_1?filter=record_date:gte:{0},account_type:eq:Treasury General Account (TGA) Closing Balance&fields=record_date,open_today_bal&page[number]=1&page[size]=300' -f '2022-01-01')

$wshosho_data = $wshosho_result
$rrp_data     = $rrp_result.repo.operations | Where-Object note -NotMatch 'This operation is a Small Value Exercise'
$tga_data     = $tga_result.data

$specs = @(
    [ordered] @{ data = $wshosho_data; date_prop = 'DATE';          prop = 'WSHOSHO' }
    [ordered] @{ data = $rrp_data;     date_prop = 'operationDate'; prop = 'totalAmtAccepted' }
    [ordered] @{ data = $tga_data;     date_prop = 'record_date';   prop = 'open_today_bal' }
)

$tbl = combine-columns-alt $specs
```

## Performance of `combine-columns-alt`

The real-world data example above results in the following data counts:

```
PS C:\Users\dharm\Dropbox\Documents> $wshosho_data.Count
1061
PS C:\Users\dharm\Dropbox\Documents> $rrp_data.Count                                                                                                      
253
PS C:\Users\dharm\Dropbox\Documents> $tga_data.Count
248
```

Running `combine-columns-alt` on these takes over 18 seconds on my system.

```
PS C:\Users\dharm\Dropbox\Documents> Measure-Command { $tbl = combine-columns-alt $specs } | Select-Object TotalSeconds     

TotalSeconds
------------
  18.9018796
```

Comment: For other performance tuning considerations, it is also important to take in accoun the size of the tables, whether the dates can be assumed to be in (ascending) order and (considering a hashtable lookup) whether it concers certain time frame (e.g. 1 year is a lookup table of only 365 days)

Comment: Hey @iRon ‍♂️. I've updated the question to mention performance. See sections `Real world data` and `Performance of combine-columns-alt`.

Comment: I think you just complicated the question. What is the 3rd table doing here? What if the `operationDate` and `record_date` aren't related? Please try to build a [mcve].

Comment: @iron, 3 tables were always part of the question in the `Sample Data` section. Check the edit history and you'll see that it was there from the beginning. I did not complicate the original question with these edits. I only added a larger dataset to demonstrate the performance degradation.

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this by using a PS module like [Join-Object](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join-Object/2.0.3).
This works similar to your SQL based approach, except it is in PowerShell.

Joining the tables, looks like this:

```
Join-Object -Left $wshosho_data -Right $rrp_data -LeftJoinProperty DATE -RightJoinProperty operationDate -Type AllInBoth
```

The output looks like this:

```
DATE       WSHOSHO   totalAmtAccepted
----       -------   ----------------
2023-02-08 8024104.0 
2023-02-15 7990467.0 
2023-02-22 7986887.0 
2023-03-01 7948534.0 
2023-03-08 7948335.0 
2023-03-15 7940014.0 
2023-03-22 7936558.0 
2023-03-29 7926131.0 
2023-04-05 7877114.0 2243011000000
2023-04-12 7877741.0 2303862000000
                     2253786000000
                     2321699000000
                     2297208000000
                     2239655000000
                     2173663000000
                     2219375000000
                     2221010000000
                     2375171000000
```

Comment: Note that that only includes the dates from WSHOSHO, not RRP. The union of dates should be included.

Comment: Yes, you can keep both join fields by adding the parameter "-KeepRightJoinProperty".